# how is this jquery app validating the username? (3rd party script)

Tags: php, jquery, validation

The tutorial that I'm trying to figure out is this:
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

The `username` field looks like this:

```
<input value="" class="validate[required,custom[noSpecialCaracters],length[0,20],ajax[ajaxUser]]" type="text" name="user" id="user" />
```

That `<input>` field has a class item named `ajax[ajaxUser]` which has its rules contained in this script (`jquery.validationEngine-en.js`).

The snippet for that item looks like this:

```
"ajaxUser":{
    "file":"validateUser.php",
    "extraData":"name=eric",
    "alertTextOk":"* This user is available",   
    "alertTextLoad":"* Loading, please wait",
    "alertText":"* This user is already taken"},
```

What I can't figure out at all is how its PHP page is working which is `validateUser.php`. Where are all those post fields coming from? I looked around and can't find a field with those names.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464616/dynamic-backgroundimages-php-gd/1128902#1128902 Nice.

Answer (score 0):

The php page (or any engine/framework you would like to use) takes the following post variables:

- **email** ced@hotmail.com
- **firstname2** karnius
- **lastname2** karnius
- **name** anything
- **user2** karnius

And returns either `true` or `false` as the entire response.  The messages defined in your question are displayed depending on which response it gets.

Answer (score 0):

The post data looks like this:

```
validateValue=karnius&validateId=user&validateError=ajaxUser
```

It appears that `validateId` is the form element name and `validateError` comes from `ajax[ajaxUser]`.

The response looks like this:

```
{"jsonValidateReturn":["user","ajaxUser","true"]}
```

The PHP code could look something like this:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['validateValue']).'"');
    $response = $result ? 'false' : 'true';
    echo json_encode(array('jsonValidateReturn' => array(
        $_POST['validateId'],
        $_POST['validateError'],
        $response)));
?>
```

(Obviously, a more complicated handler could base its behavior on `validateId` and `validateError`.)