# Passing the PHP value to a thrid party script in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

[how is this jquery app validating the username? (3rd party script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204247/how-is-this-jquery-app-validating-the-username-3rd-party-script)

Iam using the same third party script for  form validation  that was mentioned in the above question 
.Now  we have file in the third party script  known as jquery.validationEngine-en.js .so i have a field in my html known as

```
<input type="text"  id ="test1"  value ="" class ="ajax[optional,ajaxcode]">
```

in the jquery.validationEngine-en.js we have defined in this way

```
   "ajaxcode":{  
        "file":"get_custcode.php?citycode=",
        "alertText":"code is already taken",
        "alertTextOk":"", 
        "alertTextLoad":"* Checking..."
   },
```

So my problem is How do i pass the citycode (parameter ) with  some dynamic value(PHP)  which is very much mandatory at the server side script (PHP)inorder to  make sure that custcode  dowsnot exist in that city. But iam Unable to pass  the city code. here are the various things i have tried
   for passing the value

```
 "file":"get_custcode.php?citycode="+<? echo $_REQUEST['citycde']?>,

   "file":"get_custcode.php?citycode=<? echo $_REQUEST['citycde']?>",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about placing the value of the city inside a hidden form and let jQuery get the value out of it for the validation:

HTML

```
<input type="hidde" id="cityCode" value='<? echo $_REQUEST['citycde']?>' />
```

Js script

```
"file" : "get_custcode.php?citycode="+$("#cityCode").val()
```